# datetime.strptime

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Есть строка:

```
date_ = "2018-10-22 11:34:22.393092+03"
```

Я с помощью `datetime.strptime` пытаюсь привести ее к формату `datetime.datetime`:

```
normal = datetime.strptime(date_, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z")
```

Но получается исключение:

> ```
> ValueError: time data '2018-10-22 11:34:22.393092+03' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'
> ```

Получается оно из-за тайм зоны `+03`, она, как я понял, не подходит к моему формату. Как правильно вставить `%z` в этот формат, чтобы все приводилось корректно?

Comment: Почитав повнимательней документацию, я заметил, что для `%z` тайм-зона должна быть вида `+0300`. Конкатенировать исходную строку с двумя нулями, кажется мне костылем, может есть какой то другой способ?

Answer (score 2):

Можно через модуль [dateutil](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil):

```
# pip install python-dateutil
import dateutil.parser

dt = dateutil.parser.parse('2018-10-22 11:34:22.393092+03')
print(dt)  # 2018-10-22 11:34:22.393092+03:00
print(type(dt))  # <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Comment: Мне бы через стандартные модули. Но спасибо за совет

Comment: @HutadoHutado, через стандартные, похоже без некоторых костылей, не получится сделать :(